# Creating an ASP.NET Web Application without HTTPS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, https

I am trying to create a new ASP.NET Web Application. I don't want to configure my project for HTTPS. However, when I uncheck the "Configure for HTTPS" check box, MVC or Web API options are grayed out and become not available. And then if I create the app with HTTPS configuration, then when I run my app, browsers complain about the missing certification for HTTPS connection.

Is there a way to create an ASP.NET web application without HTTPS configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding what you are seeing, if you are creating a Web API, then selecting it, will automatically check MVC and Web API checkboxes on the right. These options will always be greyed out on Web API selection, Configure for HTTPS or not.

The same will apply if you select MVC, it will disable and auto check the MVC box, and allow you to check Web API. This is irrespective of whether you are configuring it to use https.

There is an alternative, if you are experiencing some weird issue and it's not working as expected. Create the App, configured for HTTPS. Then right click the project, after it is created. Select the "Debug" tab, and uncheck the "Enable SSL" checkbox. You probably won't have to do this, but I'll put it here just incase.